# How to sort similar, but not duplicate, lines of text?

Tags: sorting, duplicates, lines

I'm trying to sort a list of hundreds of thousands of lines that I've already removed many duplicates from. However, some duplicates remain where the only difference is a space, such as:

> The Hunt for Blackbeard's Treasure
>
> The Hunt for Black Beard's Treasure

I've tried using Excel, Notepad++, Java/Python and other line sorting programs, but I haven't found any solution to sort lines while ignoring specific characters, such as a space. Is there such a program?

Answer (score 0):

How about deleting all the spaces from the files and then sorting.